# Programatically run a QEMU VM instance from snapshot

Tags: system, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I have a QEMU image with a snapshot stored in it. Right now I'm using libvirt to start it.

However, I want to be able to run more than one instance out of the same image/snapshot.

I guess I can do that by cloning the virtual-hd and installing/creating a new domain (*virsh*) and then running revert from snapshot. But I want to be able to do that pretty much "on-the-fly" with as little as possible latency from the time I decide I need to run another instance of image X to the time that instance is running from the stored snapshot.

Anyone did anything like that? I started thinking maybe libvirt is not low-level enough for this ?

[EDIT: Sorry if this wasn't clear - I'm talking about a RAM+HD snapshot, not just HD snapshot, which I already know how to create...]

Thanks

Comment: This is both a programming and a system question, so I hope this is the right place.

Comment: Have you ever managed to get this to work with libvirt and not by using the `-snapshot` directly on qemu?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to run multiple concurrent qemu from the same snapshot using a command like the following.  (Obviously the `-arm`, `-kernel`, `-cpu` etc. arguments will be different in your case)

```
qemu-system-arm -hda snapshot.qcow2 -snapshot -kernel some_vmlinux \
                -serial stdio -append 'root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw'\
                -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb
```

The important argument here is `-snapshot`, so that temporary memory is used for disk writes.

What I *havent* tried is forcing a writeback to the underlying device, I suspect all manner of havoc could occur if this is possible and it happened... basically, don't forget the `-snapshot` argument!

If you want some writable storage that is *different* per instance you probably need to add a second virtual hard disk and have the common snapshot mount that somehow:

```
qemu-system-arm -hda snapshot.qcow2 -snapshot -kernel some_vmlinux \
                -serial stdio -append 'root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw'\
                -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -hdb drive_system1.img &
qemu-system-arm -hda snapshot.qcow2 -snapshot -kernel some_vmlinux \
                -serial stdio -append 'root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw'\
                -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -hdb drive_system2.img &
```

If you are using networking, dont forget to make the MAC address and any `hostfw` port values different.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I wanted. I already have a snapshot stored in the qcow2 image (can be watched using `qemu-img info <image_file>`. I want to be able to revert from THAT snapshot (also includes RAM state)

Comment: the solution above is running  from a previously created snapshot...   admittedly, it doesnt include RAM state, perhaps you could add that requirement to the question?

Comment: No worries. Havent tried that with qemu, I usually use virtual box for vms that need memory saved so I'll be watching this with interest....